# Why is it legal to declare a transient variable in a non serializable class?

Tags: java, serialization, io, transient

As for the subject title: Why is it legal to declare a transient variable in a non serializable class?
What would the use be?

Comment: I am choosing John Skeet's answer as it came first (on admission of tbodt) and the content is what I was looking for. However to get a complete answer of the question read also the tbodt Answer. One answer complete the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `transient` access modifier can be seen by code other than the serialization mechanism, and is used by some object databases to mark a data field as not persistent. Aside from that, there isn't any harm in allowing this.

Comment: I was skeeted out by about 5 seconds!

Comment: lol :) however i'll upvote anyway that you provided info that in the Jon Skeet's answer are not. cheers

Comment: I explained why in the question comment

Comment: You get the point man, I have just noticed that the second point of John Skeet's answer is not actually applicable

Answer (score 2):

Because also other serialization forms that don't requirier Serializable are able to make use of it too.

Answer (score 0):

How about if a subclass implements `Serializable`?

In any case, it is impossible for the compiler to enforce this rule, i.e. emit a compile error
based on class hierarchy (except - of course - superclass defined methods).

Comment: transient variable inherited  from a NON serializable super class, will be treated then as non-transient during serialization.