# Algorithm to avoid duplicate Cards in Card Game

Tags: java, algorithm, duplicates

I made a rookie mistake, and am trying to figure out a fix without recoding the entire program.  Here's the scenario:

I am creating 6 cards from a 52 card deck.  The cards have 2 fields: int rank and char suit.  I am pulling a random rank and suit and creating a new and unnamed instance of each card.  This is not accounting for duplicates.

So I am creating the 6 cards successfully, but I do not want the duplicates.  This may be a newbish question, but we have all been there :)  Thanks for your help!

---

```
public void displayCards(List<ImageView> disp) {
        int cardNumber = 0;
        for (ImageView c : disp) {

            cardNumber++;

            rank = rand(13) + 2;
            int i = rand(4);
            if (i == 0) {
                suit = 's';
            } else if (i == 1) {
                suit = 'h';
            } else if (i == 2) {
                suit = 'd';
            } else {
                suit = 'c';
            }

            if (cardNumber == 1) {
                dc1 = new Card(rank, suit);
            } else if (cardNumber == 2) {
                dc2 = new Card(rank, suit);
            } else if (cardNumber == 3) {
                dc3 = new Card(rank, suit);
            } else if (cardNumber == 4) {
                pc1 = new Card(rank, suit);
            } else if (cardNumber == 5) {
                pc2 = new Card(rank, suit);
            } else {
                pc3 = new Card(rank, suit);
            }}
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more as to what you mean by duplicates?

Comment: Place all 52 cards in a list and pull each card out if rather then creating a new instance each time.  This way, only the cards in the original can be used.  Don't forget to return them to the deck

Comment: of the 6 cards, i may have 5H 7D 7D 8C 9S 9H.  I want one of the 7Ds to be replaced with a new card

Comment: @MadProgrammer thats what i was trying to avoid, cuz that will create issues all over my program. i messed up by not doing that in the first place, and im looking for a quicker fix

Comment: @Evorlor can't you still use that method internally in the `displayCards` function? Instead of all the `new Card` stuff, create 52 cards before the loop, then pull one out randomly inside the loop.

Comment: It might be worth refactoring now - it will make development easier in future.

Comment: @Evorlor I can't see how you can fix unless you provide some means to control how the cards are created...You *could* create a single instance of the `Deck` instead, if that makes life easier.  Trying to dig a deeper hole is only going to make life even more unpleasant...One of the skills a developer needs to have is the ability to walk away from a bad idea or mistake ;) ... and yes, I do a lot of walking ;)

Comment: ur right madprogrammer...i do want to get better afterall. and i think a lightbulb may have just gone off thanks to everyones help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, override `equals()` and `hashCode()` in your `Card` class if you haven't done it yet.

Second, add already created cards to a `Set` (which guarantees that it won't contain duplicates)

Modify your code for something like this:

```
public void displayCards(List<ImageView> disp) {

    int cardNumber = 0;
    Set<Card> myCards = new HashMap<Card>();
    for (ImageView c : disp) {

        cardNumber++;

        Card newCard;

        do {
            rank = rand(13) + 2;
            int i = rand(4);
            if (i == 0) {
                suit = 's';
            } else if (i == 1) {
                suit = 'h';
            } else if (i == 2) {
                suit = 'd';
            } else {
                suit = 'c';
            }
            newCard = new Card(rank, suit);
        } while(myCards.contains(newCard));

        myCards.add(newCard);


        if (cardNumber == 1) {
            dc1 = newCard;
        } else if (cardNumber == 2) {
            dc2 = newCard;
        } else if (cardNumber == 3) {
            dc3 = newCard;
        } else if (cardNumber == 4) {
            pc1 = newCard;
        } else if (cardNumber == 5) {
            pc2 = newCard;
        } else {
            pc3 = newCard;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Option 1: Create a full deck (e.g., in a List) of 52 cards using two (nested) loops (all suits and all ranks). Shuffle (using `Collections.shuffle()`) the deck and take the six cards.

Option 2: Just create the number of cards you want (like you are attempting to do). Here, you will want to put each card into a `Set<Card>` until the set has the desired number of cards. Essentially, the duplicates will disappear in the set. For this to work, you need to implement `equals()` and `hashcode()` for the Card class.

Comment: public void createDeck() {
  deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
  for (int i = 2; i < 15; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    char suit;
    if (j == 0) {
     suit = 's';
    } else if (j == 1) {
     suit = 'h';
    } else if (j == 2) {
     suit = 'd';
    } else {
     suit = 'c';
    }
    deck.add(new Card(i, suit));
   }
  }
 }

Comment: i have that, but im not sure how i would use it

Comment: Call Collections.shuffle(deck) and then your six cards are given by deck.get(0), deck.get(1), ..., deck.get(5). If you keep track of how many cards you have 'dealt' from the deck, you can grab more cards without duplicates later in your code (if you need to do that).

Answer (score 2):

Create a deck of all 52 cards and extract the cards from the deck. Also you should use enumerators to represent ranks and suits.

See my answer in [What variables do I have to compare in this java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041502/what-variables-do-i-have-to-compare-in-this-java-code/18042277#18042277) for example code of cards and deck.

Comment: thats what i was trying to avoid, cuz that will create issues all over my program. i messed up by not doing that in the first place, and im looking for a quicker fix